# Не получается импортировать модуль interactions | Discord.py

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py, pip

Я следую этой документации: https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installing
Прописал в терминал `pip install -U discord-py-interactions`:

```
    Requirement already satisfied: discord-py-interactions in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from discord-py-interactions) (3.7.4.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: orjson in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from discord-py-interactions) (3.6.8)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from discord-py-interactions) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp->discord-py-interactions) (3.3)
```

Но в строке `import interactions` показывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\PycharmProjects\ХзCoin Бот\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import interactions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interactions'
```

Когда нажимаю на "Install package interactions" (я работаю в pyCharm) выдаёт следующее:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement interactions (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for interactions
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Александр\PycharmProjects\ХзCoin Бот\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой python и pyCharm, как я понял перепутались пути установки библиотек